ASP.NET Core 8 MVC & EF Core navigation property
I'm trying to use the navigation property to add related field in my controller action before returning the data to my view.
I thought it would be as easy as in the below pictures since I'm not receiving any build or syntax  error.
My model:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace LKGest.Models;

public partial class Quartier
{
    [DisplayName("Numéro du quartier")]
    public int NoQuartier { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ce champ ne peut être vide!")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Le nombre de caractères doit être inférieur à 100!")]

    [DisplayName("Nom du quartier")]
    public string NomQuartier { get; set; } = null!;

    [DisplayName("Nom de la commune")]
    public int NoCommune { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Remarques")]
    public string? RemQuartier { get; set; }

    public DateTime DteCreationDonnee { get; set; }
    public DateTime DteChgtDonnee { get; set; }

    public string MatAuteurChgtDonnee { get; set; } = null!;

    [DisplayName("In/Actif")]
    public bool Inactif { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MaisonsLocaux> MaisonsLocauxes { get; set; } = new List<MaisonsLocaux>();

    [ValidateNever]
    public virtual CommunesAbj NoCommuneNavigation { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<RessourcesHumaine> RessourcesHumaines { get; set; } = new List<RessourcesHumaine>();
}

My controller:
public IActionResult list_Quartiers()
{
    List<Quartier> liste_des_Quartiers = _db.Quartiers.Include(c => c.NoCommuneNavigation.NomCommune).ToList();
    return View(liste_des_Quartiers);
}

And this is the error I get:

System.InvalidOperationException:
'The expression 'c.NoCommuneNavigation.NomCommune' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations. For more information on including related data, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.'



What is CommunesAbj class? Does it also has a filed named "NoCommune"?

In EF Core it would be: _db.Quartiers.AsNoTracking().Include(c => c.NoCommuneNavigation).ThenInclude(ncn => ncn..NomCommune).ToList(); In general I don't recommend sending entities to views, project to a view model structure suited to exposing just the data the view needs rather than the entire domain object.

CommunesAbj  is a class and NoCommune (int) is the primary key for it

@StevePy your suggestion still give the same error.
I do have a view model for that view that I use to feed a "Select" tag.
I'm trying to get a list in which I need to display the name column (NomCommune) instead of the primary key (NoCommune)

Ah, if NomCommune is the name column it will automatically be available with just _db.Quartiers.AsNoTracking().Include(c => c.NoCommuneNavigation).ToList(); If you want to project the Quartiers to a view model that will include the NomCommune then you do not need any eager loading .Include() just reference the NomCommune via the navigation reference in a Select():
var quartiers = _db.Quartiers
   .AsNotracking()
   .Select(q => new QuartierViewModel
   {
       NoQuartier = q.NoQuartier,
       NomQuartier = q.NomQuartier,
       // ...          
       NomCommune = q.NoCommuneNavigation.NomCommune
  }).ToList();

Using Include is for retrieving entities such as when you want to edit a Quartier along with its associated NoCommune which tells EF "load this entity along with this other related one". This would give you a Quartier along with the whole NoCommuneNavigation which you can access the Commune ID as well as name, etc.
When you project using Select() you just reference the navigation properties as you need and EF will automatically compose an SQL SELECT statement based on the properties you access from the respective tables. The benefits of projection is you can reduce the number of columns being sent around, also protecting information about your data schema from prying eyes. Just avoid mixing view models with entities (I.e. selecting a related entity into the view model class)

Oh just great, works perfectly as I wanted it.
I'll work on the Select() option as it seems to provide more safety and integrity
